# Error when I try t oopen the QB template in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, quickbooks, qbfc

I am running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. I have installed the Intuiut SDK v12.0 to its default location. I copied the file "IntuitWizardQBFC.zip" and pated it into the templates folder for visual studio. The icon for the quick books template is on the interview screen but when I click on it I get an error message. It states "Could not load file or assembly 'Interop QBFC10, Version=11.0.0.132, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31d8aec64e18259' or one of it's dependencies. The system cannot find the specified file" I saw a similar post regaurding an existing application. I cannot open the template to create the first application. My machine is Windows 7 64 bit. When I write programs for class I set the target to x86 so If I can test them on older computers. This setting is usually set after the solution is created when the new project is started. Please help I am currently using access to get data from my QB data base and want to do something diffrent.

Answer (score 4):

The template wizard assembly IntuitWizardQBFC has a reference to version 11.0.0.132 of Interop.QBFC10, which is not present on your system. Go to C:\Windows\Assembly, look for Interop.QBFC10, and see what it says in the Version column. In my case, it says 11.0.0.29.

You can force Visual Studio to use version 11.0.0.29 instead of 11.0.0.132 by [redirecting assembly versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx). Edit devenv.exe.config, and just before the closing `</assemblyBinding>` tag, add this:

```
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Interop.QBFC10" publicKeyToken="31d8aec643e18259" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.132" newVersion="11.0.0.29"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Close Visual Studio if it was open; start it up, and create a new project using the template. Instead of showing the error message, it should launch the wizard.

Comment: AT:Adam Nicely done.  Works for me. :)                                                   @arlen-beiler  You're probably looking for the devenv.exe.config in whichever version of VS compiler you're using.  Mine was found in:  "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0"

Answer (score 0):

Try installing QBFC10 and then try the template. It is possible I forgot to update the template when SDK 12 was built.

You can download QBFC10 from the same location you got the SDK.

William

Comment: That did not work. Does the template give any advantage other than having the refrences preset? If I open a blank template and add the refrences manually I can connect to my QB file.

Comment: William, is this problem fixed yet? I'm having the same problem. Have you found a workaround

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded the QuickBooks Desktop SDK v13 today and it still has this issue with the VS.NET Project Wizard.

Following up on Adam C's post above, the complete path to this node in the devenv.exe.config is as follows:

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    ...
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            ...
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="Interop.QBFC10" publicKeyToken="31d8aec643e18259" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.132" newVersion="11.0.0.29"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            ...
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    ...
</configuration>
```